# Sensors values change / jacl

Tags: sensors

Is there any way to hack, overwrite x,y,z and other values of sensors? I mean I want to write a bot to sensor based games to test them. But I cannot change the source of games or stock api of the phone meaning I cannot use custom rom. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: this is rather SO question?